# Connect NetBeans to Xdebug on a Docker container

Tags: docker, netbeans, xdebug

I tried to connect NetBeans to Xdebug located in a container PHP within Ubuntu.

The problem is that if I launch the container with the option `--net=host` everything is OK, but if I try use the default one (bridge), NetBeans can reach the container but the container can't reach my host environment.

This is my xdebug ini conf:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Notice that Xdebug log explicitly reports that xdebug can't find getadress.

There is a way to connect a bridged container to host environment?

Comment: Depending on your machine setup you can use the docker0 interface IP address. It doesn't change but it's not a "good" solution.

Comment: My docker0 interface ip is 172.17.0.1, do you mean xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1 ?

Comment: yep... I found also this src that might be interesting: https://gist.github.com/chadrien/c90927ec2d160ffea9c4

Comment: I tried yesterday and nothing, but today I disabled ufw and it works. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have solved that already, but just in case: have you tried with `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`? **P.S.** It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around (https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication)

Comment: Yes. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xdebug3, I am using the following settings in my xdebug.ini file:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

The port number of 9003 matches the value set in Netbeans Preferences - PHP - Debugging - Debugger Port. I can't remember the default, but it's probably 9000.

This assumes that you're using the default "bridged network" mode for Docher. What's happening here is that `host.docker.internal` is telling Xdebug to connect to the container's host - i.e. your dev machine which is running Netbeans.